# Display large number on y-axis in python-nvd3

Tags: python, d3.js, flask, nvd3.js

One way of displaying large numbers on the y-axis is the shift the margin: [Y axis label not displaying large numbers - Multi-Bar Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297393/y-axis-label-not-displaying-large-numbers-multi-bar-chart). How do adjust the `margin` parameter in python-nvd3? Can you instead write the exponent at the top like 10^6 and mark the y-axis as 2.5 ,3.0 etc. instead of writing 25,00,000 , 30,00,000 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to format the number of y-axis. You can use tickFormat option.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_tickFormat

Something like:

```
.tickFormat(function(d) { return d / Math.pow(10,6) }
```

Comment: yes, I want to format the number on y-axis, but using python bindings for nvd3, not the JavaScript directly

Comment: Does python-nvd3 has tickFormat function? I know nvd3 has it.

Comment: The documentation is not comprehensive. I could not find it here:[link](http://python-nvd3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/classes-doc/NVD3Chart.html).

Comment: Which chart class are you using? It looks like y-axis tickformat is not supported. You'll have to extend the package to pass in new arg. https://github.com/areski/python-nvd3/search?q=tickformat&ref=cmdform

Comment: Oh ok. I am using the lineChart. do I need to modify the source file ?

Comment: Yes, modify this file: https://github.com/areski/python-nvd3/blob/89be855154ac7b4d54590494adc7c7631a3e67a7/nvd3/lineChart.py and change this tickFormat: chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));